# I have a dictionary {string and int}. How do I compare integers values and not the keys within the same dictionary(python)

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary of people, I want to sort people alphabetically by name IF they are the same age, and to sort people descending by age if they are different age. So essentually, I need to return two outputs. Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't take in account the condition. How do I just compare the age value for every item and add it into a different list then sort it?

```
people = {'Steve' : 20 , 'David': 21 , 'Andrew' : 19 , 'Bruce': 22 ,'James' : 20 , 'Dave': 26 ,'Smith' : 19}
print('Sorted People in Alphabetical Order: ', dict(sorted(people.items())))
print('Sorted People in Numerical Order: ',dict(sorted(people.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])))
```

My wanted output is
Sorted Same Age People in Alphabetical Order: {(Andrew,19), (James,20), (Smith, 19), (Steve, 20)}

Sorted Different Ages by Age:{(David,21), (Bruce,22), (Dave,26)}

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `tuple` to `key` of `sorted`. First sort based on age then sort base alphabet.

```
people = {'Steve' : 20 , 'David': 21 , 'Andrew' : 19 , 'Bruce': 22 ,'James' : 20 , 'Dave': 26 ,'Smith' : 19}

res = dict(sorted(people.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0])))
# -------------------------------------------x[1]^^^ is value -> age
# ---------------------------------------------------x[0]^^^ is key -> alphabet
print(res)
```

Output:

```
{'Andrew': 19,
 'Smith': 19,
 'James': 20,
 'Steve': 20,
 'David': 21,
 'Bruce': 22,
 'Dave': 26}
```